# xcode - how extract a part of string separated by character "

Tags: ios, string

I have a string and I need to extract the complete http address in order to pass it to Safari.

My string is:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Example Street, 1,  Rome">Example Street, 1</a>
```

How coulg get only:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Example Street, 1,  Rome
```

that is included into " special character?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the fastest solution, but probably the shortest one

```
[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""][1];
```

If there is a chance that yourString will not have two " symbols you should check

```
[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""].length
```

first

Comment: Yes! thannks so much!